# Displaying timer of an alarm using button

Tags: java, android, mobile, timer, alarm

I have this code where I made 2 buttons, one to set an alarm and one for checking the time left until the alarm going off. Currently, I'm struggling with the second button which checking the timer. Can someone help me out?

Here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final TextView lefty = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.left);



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            Long preTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

            calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,8);

            Long postTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
            Long delay = postTime - preTime;

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NotificationReceiver.class);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,pendingIntent);

            CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(delay, 1) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    final int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
                    final int minutes = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                    final int hour = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           lefty.setText( hour + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds);
                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            };
            timer.start();
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        "some code"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For do my answer and help you, i will completing your code and add a TextView for exemple for put the time on it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // modify here
    private Calendar myTimer = null;
    private TextView myTextView = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        final TextView lefty = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.left);


        // modify here
        myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
        myTimer = Calendar.getInstance();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                Long preTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
                Long postTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                Long delay = postTime - preTime;
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationReceiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
                CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(delay, 1) {
                    @Override
                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        final int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
                        final int minutes = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                        final int hour = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

                        // modify here
                        myTimer.set(Calendar.SECOND, seconds);
                        myTimer.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);
                        myTimer.set(Calendar.HOUR, hour);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                lefty.setText(hour + " : " + minutes + " : " + seconds);
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                };
                timer.start();
            }
        });


        // modify here
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String myString = new SimpleDateFormat("hh : mm : ss").format(myTimer);
                myTextView.setText(myString);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm sorry but your code doesn't work, it said "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad class: class java.util.GregorianCalendar" thanks btw

Comment: have you try to add `getTime()` for get the string ?
 `format(myTimer.getTime());`

Comment: it seems that the code just displaying the current time instead the remaining time left until the alarm goes off